# Extract Ethernet, IP header, TCP and payload from socket recv Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

How can I extract Extract Ethernet, IP header, TCP and payload from **socket.recv** in Python
Right now I can obtain information above using **socket.recvfrom()**:

```
    packet = s.recvfrom(NETWORK_MAX_SIZE)
    packet = packet[0] 
    #parse ethernet header
    eth_length = 14
    eth_header = packet[:eth_length]
    eth = unpack('!6s6sH' , eth_header)
    eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth[2])
    t = iph_length + eth_length
    tcp_header = packet[t:t+20]
    #now unpack them :)
    tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_header)
    source_port = tcph[0]
    dest_port = tcph[1]
    sequence = tcph[2]
    acknowledgement = tcph[3]
    doff_reserved = tcph[4]
    tcph_length = doff_reserved >> 4
    h_size = eth_length + iph_length + tcph_length * 4
    data_size = len(packet) - h_size
    #get data from the packet
    data = packet[h_size:]
```

Reference:
http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/

When I use same function by a fragmented TCP packet and call **socket.recv()** I get errors when unpacking tcpheader.

Thanks

Comment: The TCP header isn't always 20 bytes- you have to inspect the header for the data offset value to know where the header ends- FYI

Answer (score 1):

Thanks I recognized that **socket.recv()** returns a type str and **socket.recvfrom()** returns a tuple type, hence for socket.recv() I omitted packet = packet[0].
I will update code to handle TCP header to be variable.