# Obtain source and destination IP address from socket.recv versus s.recvfrom

Tags: python, sockets

I have programmed a packet capture tool in python, I'm using the following code:

```
packet = socket.recv(sipLocatorConfig.NETWORK_TCP_MAX_SIZE)
eth_length = 14
ip_header = packet[eth_length:20+eth_length]          
#now unpack them 
iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)
version_ihl = iph[0]
version = version_ihl >> 4
ihl = version_ihl & 0xF
iph_length = ihl * 4
ttl = iph[5]
protocol = iph[6]
t = iph_length + eth_length           
tcp_header = packet[t:t+20]
tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH',tcp_header)
source_port = tcph[0]
dest_port = tcph[1]
s_addr1 = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
d_addr1 = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
'_socketobject' object has no attribute 'inet_ntoa'
```

How to obtain source address and destination address of my captured packet ?
This works fine with `packet = s.recvfrom(sipLocatorConfig.NETWORK_MAX_SIZE)`
Thanks

Comment: So why aren't you using recvfrom() then, as it works? The information simply isn't available via recv().

Comment: Hi EJP, I tried that but required to create additional code to parse the packet info I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961428/extract-ethernet-ip-header-tcp-and-payload-from-socket-recv-python/19966175#19966175